# Transform Array of level+data to List tree structure

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

I am writing a program that takes in an array and then makes a ul tree type structure that is collapsible. I am doing this in java script. I get strings in an array like this:

```
{"1, Dog, true"},
{"2, German Shepard, true"},
{"3, Spotty, true"},
{"2, Jack Russel, true"},
{"3, Blacky, true"},
{"1, Cats, true"},
{"1, Horses, true"}
```

This should produce

- Dog

  - German Shepard

    - Sptty
  - Jack Russel

    - Blacky
- Cats
- Horses

I have tried making the array multi dimensional and just iterating through that, but there is sometimes 4 levels and a possibility of it becoming 5. True will make the list item green while false will make the list item red. I split the array by "," and if the number is bigger than the previous one I make a new ul, if the number is smaller than I close a ul, but I have trouble when the previous number is smaller by >2. Some assistance will be great thanks.

Comment: You get your data in a really awful way. Actually you have an array of objects where each object is simply a string. Any way that you can change the returned data too? moreover in this way the only road you can walk through is to parse the strings, do you have only these 3 kinds of animal or more/dynamic too can be added?

Comment: I can change it, I am running a jar in NodeJS that runs tests using selenium , they provide output to the terminal in that format but I can get it changed. There is many animal types and it should be able to accommodate many more animal types. What is the best format that can allow it to be made into a list?

Comment: could you explain me what the first int and the last bool stand for? just to create an object with meaningful properties names

Comment: The first int was the level of it, so 1 is type of animal, 2 is breed, 3 is name. the bool is whether is passed a test, just a representation that the data is correct.

Comment: So third parameter is useless I suppose. You can have a structure like this one: 
`var animals = [
  {
    Dogs: [
       German Shepard: {
         name: "Spotty",
         age: 5
       }
    ]
  }
];`
// and so on
Does it suit you? 
Please if so, post also your node.js code where you get this list and we can convert it in a proper way

Comment: I use the 3rd parameter to decide what is the background colour, true is green and false is red. The nodejs code to get the list is this, `var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;                        
child = exec('java -jar /root/WebstormProjects/untitled1/myapp/testOutput.jar',
  function (error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log(stdout);
    if(error !== null){
      console.log(stderr);
    }
  });`

Comment: From there I think I will make it to a JSON, then pass it to my templating engine, then make it into a ul using this http://jsfiddle.net/BvDW3/

Comment: oh sorry I read "text" not "test" -.- ok got it, but few more questions:
1) Are you using protractor too for your e2e tests? 
2) Would it be possible that you have multiple times the same string? for example `{"2, German Shepard, true"}` and `{"2, German Shepard, false"}`
3) I don't know what are you doing, but they seem more unit tests than e2e tests. Are you sure that they can't be covered through unit tests only?

Comment: 4) Why to do you have this inconsistency among names? "horses" "cats" "dog" (singular)

Comment: Thanks, 1.) Not using that yet 2.) It is not possible 3.) I am breaking a page down into blocks and then making a nice web interface used to test production environment  using selenium webdriver after the page load. So I break one section like this, WebElement Header; WebElement Header_Title, the "_" starts making the hierarchy. So the number of occurrences of _ represents the level. So that would make {"0, Header, true"}, {"1, Title",true}, then I make a collapsible list so developers can check what element is working and what is not working.

Comment: ok and which framework are you using for testing? mocha? jasmine? qunit? just because a lot of them have really nice plugins for having HTML reports already, so you don't need to invent back the wheel again. From my understanding, you are finding a way to create HTML reports of the tests results. Isn't it?

Comment: It may be a very bad way of doing it. but it's my first time doing it. I only see other people put it into excel sheets.

Comment: I am not using any right now, yes that is what I am doing. Let me look into using one of those.

Comment: I was just grabbing the elements and writing my own test in java, so does this image show and does this link work to the right page, is this number in the right range. Then passing it to NodeJS using a JAR and hopefully making a collapsible list.

Comment: yeah I think that's the best road to walk on. If you want I can create a script to change your format but I think that if we work to use a testing framework it may be really better. Do the tests are executed by developers? or do you write them?

Comment: ok if you want to, I can change your format to create it but in my opinion if you are testing a webapp as I think, you should switch to js tests using unit tests inside the code and e2e tests with selenium/protractor, but all using js and not java

Comment: Thanks for the information! I think I can try and format the scripts myself thanks for the offer, I think I will work towards using one of those scripts. I write the scripts and the developers can rerun them using the web interface at any time.

Comment: Thanks I will look at using js with selenium/protractor. I always preferred JS, but I have been using java a lot recently. Will look at switching in the next few days thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So transform this to JSON, like

```
{
   "Dog" : {
     "isGood":true,
     "German Shepherd":{

     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually very similar to what I am trying to accomplish, but how do I transform those strings to a JSON or a list?